View in infinite creation loop
In my app, the navigation should be ArmyListView -> ArmyListDetailsView -> IncludedUnitScreenView
My ArmyListView screen creates a NavigationStack and moving on to the ArmyListDetailsView works fine. When I click an item on the ArmyListDetailsView, the IncludedUnitScreenView never opens and it looks like it's stuck in an infinite loop of creating the view.
I don't understand why this is happening when the first navigation worked fine.
Here's my code for ArmyListDetailsView
struct ArmyListDetailsView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var theIncludedUnits: [IncludedUnit]
    @Query private var theArmyList: [ArmyList]
    @State var shouldPresentSheet = false
    
    init(armyList: String = "") {
        let includedUnitsPredicate = #Predicate<IncludedUnit> { includedUnit in
            armyList.isEmpty || includedUnit.armyList.localizedStandardContains(armyList)
        }
        _theIncludedUnits = Query(filter: includedUnitsPredicate, sort: \IncludedUnit.armyList)
        
        let armyListPredicate = #Predicate<ArmyList> { armylist in
            armyList.isEmpty || armylist.listTitle.localizedStandardContains(armyList)
        }
        _theArmyList = Query(filter: armyListPredicate, sort: \ArmyList.listTitle)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let armyList = theArmyList.first.unsafelyUnwrapped
        List {
            Section(header: Text("List Details")) {
                ArmyListCoreDetails(theArmyList: armyList)
            }
            
            if !theIncludedUnits.isEmpty {
                let groupedIncludedUnits = Dictionary(grouping: theIncludedUnits, by: \.category)
                ForEach(Array(groupedIncludedUnits.keys), id: \.self) { category in
                    Section(header: Text(category)) {
                        let categoryIncludedUnits = getIncludedUnitsForCategory(theCategory: category, theIncludedUnits: groupedIncludedUnits)
                        
                        ForEach(categoryIncludedUnits, id: \.id) { theIncludedUnit in
                            NavigationLink {
                                IncludedUnitScreenView(theIncludedUnitId: theIncludedUnit.id,
                                                       theIncludedUnit: theIncludedUnit)
                            } label: {
                                IncludedUnitRow(includedUnit: theIncludedUnit)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ContentUnavailableView {
                    Label("No units have been added to this list.\nPress + to choose some.", systemImage: "doc.on.doc")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(armyList.listTitle)
    }

...and the code for IncludedUnitScreenView
struct IncludedUnitScreenView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var theUnitCompositions: [UnitComposition]
    @Query private var theLoadouts: [Loadout]
    @State private var theIncludedUnit: IncludedUnit
    @State private var theIncludedUnitId: Int
    
    init(theIncludedUnitId: Int = 0, theIncludedUnit: IncludedUnit) {
        let unitCompositionPredicate = #Predicate<UnitComposition> { unitComposition in
            theIncludedUnitId == 0 || unitComposition.includedUnitId == theIncludedUnitId
        }
        _theUnitCompositions = Query(filter: unitCompositionPredicate)
        
        let loadoutPredicate = #Predicate<Loadout> { loadout in
            theIncludedUnitId == 0 || loadout.includedUnitId == theIncludedUnitId
        }
        _theLoadouts = Query(filter: loadoutPredicate)
        
        self.theIncludedUnit = theIncludedUnit
        self.theIncludedUnitId = theIncludedUnitId
        
        NSLog("IncludedUnitScreenView: Completed the init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Unit Details")) {
                IncludedUnitCoreDetails(theIncludedUnit: theIncludedUnit)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Models")) {
                ForEach(theUnitCompositions, id: \.model) { theUnitComposition in
                    NavigationLink {
                        LoadoutListView(theLoadoutList: theLoadouts.filter {$0.model == theUnitComposition.model})
                    } label: {
                        IncludedUnitDetailsRow(
                            theIncludedUnit: theIncludedUnit,
                            theUnitComposition: theUnitComposition,
                            theLoadouts: theLoadouts.filter {$0.model == theUnitComposition.model}
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I can see the infinite loop by the NSLog statements in the debug window.

You can use let _ = Self._printChanges() inside the body property to track view updates, maybe this could be helpful.

Note, in your IncludedUnitScreenView,
you probably should have let theIncludedUnit: IncludedUnit.
If you still want @State, then in init{...} you should have self._theIncludedUnit = State(initialValue: theIncludedUnit), but I would try let.
And of course you should be using NavigationStack.

When it's starting the loop, pause the debugguer, check the stacktrace, and you might see then who's creating the loop and the starting point

On second thought, in your IncludedUnitScreenView, you should not have
@State private var theIncludedUnit: IncludedUnit and
@State private var theIncludedUnitId: Int, use let ...

Thanks @workingdogsupportUkraine. You're right, they should not be @State. I've changed them to let but still getting the same problem.
I've changed them to
let theIncludedUnit: IncludedUnit and
let theIncludedUnitId: Int

I managed to get this to work in the end - the problem was my misunderstanding of how Query works. When I changed these to fetch statements instead everything works as expected.
Thanks for your help everyone
